# 'make' command error while installing RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n driver

Tags: wifi, drivers, realtek

```
lspci -nn | grep -i network

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
```

I'm trying to install above wifi drivers in RHEL 7.2 (HP laptop), steps followed by the error message.

```
yum install rpmfusion-nonfree-release-7-4.noarch
yum install rpmfusion-free-release-7-4.noarch
yum install kernel-headers
yum install kernel-devel

git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
```

After cloning and running below command, I've encountered an error.

```
[root@oracle-12c-localdomain rtlwifi_new]# make clean
[root@oracle-12c-localdomain rtlwifi_new]# make
```

Part of error is pasted below:

```
    make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64/build M=/home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.o
In file included from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.c:26:0:
/home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/wifi.h:67:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_data’
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/wifi.h:33,
                 from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1985:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_data’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_data(struct sk_buff *skb, const void *data,
                     ^
In file included from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.c:26:0:
/home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/wifi.h:77:21: error: redefinition of ‘skb_put_zero’
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from include/linux/if_ether.h:23:0,
                 from include/linux/etherdevice.h:25,
                 from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/wifi.h:33,
                 from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.c:26:
include/linux/skbuff.h:1976:21: note: previous definition of ‘skb_put_zero’ was here
 static inline void *skb_put_zero(struct sk_buff *skb, unsigned int len)
                     ^
In file included from /home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/base.c:26:0:
/home/gsk/Downloads/rtlwifi_new/wifi.h:96:15: error: conflicting types for ‘time64_t’
 typedef __s32 time64_t;
               ^
```

Any lead on this please. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The very first line of the README says: "This code will build on any kernel 4.2 and newer". You cannot use this driver with RHEL 7. You should open a support case with Red Hat for further assistance.